# Как в виртуальное окружение в Python добавить библиотеки которые уже установлены в самом компьютере глобально , а не онлайн через pip?

Tags: python, django, library, venv

Django хочу добавить не через pip (Интернета нету), а ту который уже установлен в windows.

Вопрос вроде понятен и ясен

Answer (score -1):

Можно воспользоваться командой **`--system-site-packages`** при создании виртуального окружения.
Вот как это делается:

1. Откройте командную строку (терминал).
2. Перейдите в каталог, где вы хотите создать виртуальное окружение.
3. Выполните следующую команду, чтобы создать виртуальное окружение с доступом к глобально установленным библиотекам:

`python -m venv myenv --system-site-packages`

Замените myenv на имя вашего виртуального окружения.

4. Активируйте виртуальное окружение:

   - В Windows:

     `myenv\Scripts\activate`
   - В macOS и Linux:

     `source myenv/bin/activate`

Comment: А потом можно типо, pip install django? И он возьмёт Джанго из ПК а не из интернета? И не только Джанго а остальные библиотеки тоже?

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли. Если вы создали виртуальное окружение с опцией `--system-site-packages`, то внутри этого виртуального окружения Python будет использовать уже установленные глобально библиотеки. То есть, если вы выполните `pip install django`, Python возьмет Django из глобально установленных библиотек на вашем компьютере, а не загрузит его из интернета.

То же самое будет относиться и к другим библиотекам. Вы сможете использовать глобально установленные библиотеки внутри этого виртуального окружения без повторной загрузки из интернета.